# Artifactory weird repository link and "Bad Request" error

Tags: docker, artifactory

I just finished  the installation and configuration of JFrog Artifactory and added a repository.

Everything went just fine until I tried to deploy something. I took a look at the link displayed in the artifacts tab and it looks incorrect.

`(null)://<my-domain>:(null)/artifactory/test-repo/`

Everything else is just working fine. I've installed it in a docker container and configured a ReverseProxy in Apache to redirtect requests to HTTPS and my domain name.

```
Docker Version: Docker Engine - Community 20.10.2
Artifactory Version: 7.12.6 OSS
Apache Version: 2.4.29
Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (all latest updates installed)
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Based on our investigation, there is no issue with the specific version or the Artifactory flavor (OSS). I suggest to do two actions that will solve this issue from occurring:

1. Check once again your Tomcat configurations - might be the reason for the strange null in the URL.
2. Use HTTP and not HTTPS - we do not support HTTPS requests in this specific installation and environment.
   [generic-local path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqgez.png) [artifact path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbbHY.png)

For more details, you can look in our [Wiki](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Configuring+NGINX)!

Comment: suggestion: improve your answer by adding the relevant link within wiki